# Does Thread.currentThread().setName() call the threads run method?

Tags: java

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{
   MyRunnable(String name)
   {
      new Thread(this, name).start();
   }
   public void run()
   {
       System.out.println("run() called by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
   }
}
public class TestClass
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
      Thread.currentThread().setName("First");
      MyRunnable mr = new MyRunnable("MyRunnable");
      mr.run();
      Thread.currentThread().setName("Second");
      mr.run();
   }
}
```

The output will be 
main,
First,
Second,
MyRunnable

why does a call to Thread.currentThread().setName("First"); call the run() method?

Comment: What makes you think it does?

Comment: `new Thread(this, name).start();` in a ctor? No, NO, **NO**. Never, ever do this. Not even as a joke.

Comment: You're dealing with a race condition.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't. What you're observing is a [*race condition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Just because you start a new `Thread` in the `MyRunnable` constructor, doesn't mean it will execute before the `mr.run()` calls in your `main()` method. There is overhead associated with starting the the thread and that takes time. If you inserted a `Thread.sleep()` into your `main()` method, the output will change.